# Load More button makes page jump to the top

Tags: meteor

I want my page to not jump to the top when the user clicks "Load More". As in this example. An example of the desired effect is http://microscope.meteor.com/.

I'm using Iron:Router

```
template(name="articlesList")
  .articles
    each articles
      +articleItem

  .show-more-news-container
    if articlesReady
      if nextPath
        a(id="show-more-news-link", class="show-more-news-link") Show More News
    else
      +spinner


Template.articlesList.events
  'click #show-more-news-link': (e,t)->
    e.preventDefault()
    @loadMoreHandler()

Router.route '/news/top/:articlesLimit?',
 name: 'articlesListTop'
 template: 'articlesList'
 controller: 'ArticlesListController'

@ArticlesListController = RouteController.extend({
  template: 'articlesList'
  increment: 4
  articlesLimit: ->
    parseInt(this.params.articlesLimit) or @increment
  subscriptions: ->
    @articlesSub = Meteor.subscribe 'articlesData', @articlesLimit()
  articles: ->
   Posts.find {}, { sort: {submitted: -1} }
  data: ->
    hasMoreArticles = @articles().count() == @articlesLimit()
    nextPath = @router.path('articlesListTop', {articlesLimit: @articlesLimit() + @increment})

    return {
      articles: @articles()
      articlesReady: @articlesSub.ready()
      nextPath: if hasMoreArticles then nextPath else null
      loadMoreHandler: ->
       Router.go(nextPath)
    }
})
```

This code successfully makes my load-more button work, but it also makes my page jump to the top with each click. Anyone know what might cause this behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. I still had another waitOn function with user subscription defined in RouterController, which caused the page to jump upwards cause it went to the loading template for a few nano seconds each time.